# Is sun orbiting the center of the Milky Way?

Tags: astrophysics, orbital-motion, sun, galaxies, milky-way

Are all the celestial bodies in our galaxy (along with the Sun) orbiting the center of the Milky Way Galaxy?

Comment: Yes, it is. Thanks.